# Why are muy uploaded files deleted on Heroku when I push a new version of the application?

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

On my Symfony project, I store uploaded pictures and documents on the directory `public/upload/`

But when the dyno is rebuilt (push changes from staging to prod, change configuration variables, etc), everything is deleted there.

I don’t know what can be done with Heroku so that it saves some directories during when rebuilding the application image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file-system for a Heroku app is re-built each a dyno is started. Storing any user-generated content there is a recipe for failure.

You should store these files somewhere else. Either a remote file-system, database, or anything that does not depend on the application container.

Heroku has a [generic help page for this](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), and they advise their users to [use S3 to handle their users uploads](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-php).